# Integrate Pollfish to next.js project

Tags: next.js

I am building a next.js project where I am trying to add pollfish. I tried to add this by next/script tag but it is not working as I have to pass the user id to pollfish config.
I tried to use js script tag as well. It is working but getting server error where that script tag isn't recognized by the server. then i tried to add this by creating a function where I am creating srcipt tag by document.createElement and then passing the config file in the script.innerHtml. and pass this function in the useEffect. I want is that while I have the user info then this script adding function will trigger inside the useEffect and the pollfish servey UI will appeared. but as the functions are added in the home page, the useEffect initially load and trigger the function without the user id, and when user logged in and the user id pass in the config file the useEffect trigger again and the script functions also triggered but the UI is still the same one as before..
can anyone help me in this how to integrate pollfish perfectly in next.js project?
This is the functions file that are using for creating the script tag -

```
    export const addPollfish = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://storage.googleapis.com/pollfish_production/sdk/webplugin/pollfish.min.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};

export const addJquery = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

and this is my homepage where the useEffect are added -

```
const { userInfo } = useContext(AllContext);
  const [user, setUser] = userInfo;

  const customSurveyFinished = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const addPollfishConfig = (userId: number) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = `
  var pollfishConfig = {
    api_key: "${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POLLFISH_CONFIG}",
    debug: true,
    user_id: "${userId}",
    request_uuid: "${userId}",
    surveyCompletedCallback: ${customSurveyFinished},
  };
  `;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REST_API_ENDPOINT}/accounts/v1/user/`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem("nr_access_token")}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUser(data);
        console.log(data);
        // if (data.id) {
        //   addJquery();
        //   addPollfishConfig(data.id);
        //   addPollfish();
        // }
        addJquery();
        addPollfishConfig(data.id);
        addPollfish();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Add static scripts directly** - You should continue to add jQuery and pollfish script via `next/script` - So two script tags one with a config object, Do not add these as a response to data or within the `useeffect` block because it would cause unnecessary side effects
2. **Utilize plugin ready and restart functions** - Reviewing the pollfish documentation, they provide additional `ready`, `restart` like operations, see `showFullSurvey()` etc. https://www.pollfish.com/docs/webplugin - Once you get the data back which has the ID, then set the ID and launch the script via `window.` functions of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your help..I tried to add the scripts using next/script 
i tried to add the pollfishConfig script before the plugin
but it is not working as I wanted... I used the ready function as well...
I want to trigger the function when the user loggedin to the website otherwise the script won't run. but I can't pass the user id in the script after user loggedin. instead of the object script created multiple times while I see the inspect...

Comment: Is it possible to create this in stackblitz to see your approach?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-rm6wyn?file=pages%2Findex.js
you can check this link..I just add the script tags...

Comment: Hi there, i see that after fixing for jquery and other dependencies, we are upto a point where `user.id` is not valid with a 406 from pollfish, you should try it out with a valid user id and confirm if it gets you where you need to be, if it works I can explain the changes done. - Best of luck! 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-1bpwtu?devtoolsheight=33&file=pages/index.js

Comment: I have tried without user_id but it is so randomly generated the pollfish indicator...
is there any way that I can show the indicator by a click event on a buitton?

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding you, did you try with a valid user_id? Did your original issue get solved?

Comment: hi, i solved the original issue for loading the script with dynamic user_id. But I need to show the pollfish indicator whenever users click on a button. But it is not working perfectly. Sometime it is working and sometime it is not. is there any hint or solution to this issue?

Comment: I would suggest adding a stackblitz to show a fully functioning example.